# Find path between 2 given city in graph but with condition ( need to visit checkpoint city after K step)

Tags: graph-algorithm

I just learn about DFS,BFS, and some other shortest path algorithm but I can't solve this excercise.

Some city has food supply in it. Some don't. We want to walk from "start" to "destination" but with condition that we can go maximum of K step before we run out of food.

(* means city has food supply to pick up)

For example,  for the case K = 3

We cannot go from A to G since there is no food supply along the way, so we die at city D (3 steps without food)

A* ----B----C----D----E----F----G*

But if city C and F has food supply, we can go from A to G by picking up food at city C and F then continue to G

A* ----B----C* ----D----E----F* ----G*

any idea?

(we can assume that start and destination always contain food supply)

(food don't stack, u will die in 3 step after picking up the lastest food)

(cannot visit city more than once)

Comment: hey what time complexity you wanna achieve?

Comment: any , as long as it work, XD

Comment: i have suggested an algorithm with complexity of number of nodes*max_distance, using dp and dfs,ask me if you have a problem and mark it correct , if you are satisfied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take an array , let say it arr[number of nodes][distance] and mark it all to -1,now start from a, here number of nodes denote on which node you are and distance denote how much distance from the nearest food node, now run a dfs on a and if you travel a node let say b, with the distance from the nearest food node let say 2, mark arr[node b][2]=1(1 signifies it has been travelled) , now if you again reach node b with the same distance 2(maybe from some other node not node a), you will say i cant reach the end node through this path,now if you reach any food node lets call it c,make the distance 0 i.e. mark arr[c node][0]=1,now if you are able to reach the final node this way , success otherwise you cant reach the final node.
Heres a sample algo,

```
void funct(int node,int distance,int max_distance,int final_node){
    if(node==final_node):
        final_node can be reached
    if(distance>max_distance):
         return
    if(node == food_node):
        dist=0
    else:
        dist=distance
    if (arr[node][dist]==1):
        return
    for all the nearby node:
        arr[node][dist]=1
        funct(nearby node,dist+1,max_distance,final_node)
```

here in your case final node is G,max_distance is 3,arr is two dimentional array

Comment: Rather than tracking distance, i keep track of move i have left before i die like hp in video game, ie moving cost -1 hp. Pick up food restore life to maximum hp.

Thank you so much for you advise on DFS. I apply your general concept and get it to work now. .Thank you.